# Where to place function to fetch data from server when waiting for location data

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, android-activity, geolocation

I'm building an application that has to get data from the server according to the latitude and longitude get by Google Play Services Location API. I'm not able to figure out where to place the functions to get location and to fetch data from server. I'm going to explain me better. When the application start I have to get the last known location and I have seen that this is possible through

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CurrentGeolocation currentGeolocation = CurrentGeolocation.get(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mCurrentGeolocation.connectGoogleApiClient();
}
```

**CurrentGeolocation**

```
public static CurrentGeolocation get(Context appContext) {
        if (sCurrentGeolocation == null) {
            sCurrentGeolocation = new CurrentGeolocation(appContext.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sCurrentGeolocation;
    }

    private CurrentGeolocation(Context appContext) {
        mAppContext = appContext;
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        // create the POJO to store the last known location
        mCurrentGeolocationEntity = new CurrentGeolocationEntity();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoggleApiClient");
        if (mCurrentGeolocationEntity.getmLastLocation() == null) {
            mCurrentGeolocationEntity.setmLastLocation(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient));
        }

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
```

my problem is I don't know where place exactly the function to retrieve data from the server. I'm using Volley library and I have already written the data. What do you suggest?

Comment: Is there a particular workflow or process you are following to fetch the data? If not, why not place it in onConnected?

Comment: It is right what I have thought to do but my problem is how to fill the fields in the fragment if I don't have their visibility

Comment: In every examples I have seen all the things are merged in one activity or in one single fragment but in a real app, it is quite unthinkable to merge all in a single activity and I have some issues in imagine how to link everything

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the visibility of the fragment due to it not being loaded yet, you can try 2 things. The first is using ViewTreeObserver. You could use ViewTreeObserver to wait for your fragment or view to finish loading then fetch your data. Here is an example using a view:

```
 ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
      viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
          yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
          // Do your fetch and data insert to view here.

        ...
        }
      });
    }
```

The next one you can try is to do your fetching using a runnable. Example:

```
YourLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.BoxesLinearLayout);
YourLayout .post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your fetch and data insert to view here.

        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: but where should I place them? Inside onConnected?

Comment: From what I understand, yes, inside the onConnected() section.

Comment: But I don't have inside CurrentGeolocation any reference to view